# Dates: 09/04/2018 Vs. 9/4/2018

Tags: british-english, dates

Which of the following way of writing date is more common or recommended for using in British English in official and formal documents, and why?

> **0**9/**0**4/2018

Vs.

> 9/4/2018

Or they are both the same and it's a matter of style?

Comment: I don't think there is a rule. Some also write: 9/04/2018. It depends on the "style sheet" you want to use.

Comment: Apparently ISO 8601 is standard for many applications, with the notation YYYY-MM-DD.   This is probably not common in correspondence, but is preferred when accuracy and compatibility are factors.  It's good that you limited this to **British** English, but you should go further and define the specific context the date will be used.

Comment: @Andrew. Done. When I saw your question firstly I thought that your answer is sarcasm but then I found that it is amazing comment when I found this ISO protocol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: If you want to be understood internationally, 4 JUL 2018, 18 AUG 1975.

Comment: @Archimedean_Point thanks, glad this is useful information.  In things like medicine and engineering, ISO 8601 is clear and unambiguous, while something like 9-4-2018 is not.  In the US this is commonly interpreted as *September 4th, 2018*, but elsewhere in the world it may be *April 9th, 2018*.  That being said, I think your answer will still depend on *specific* context -- for example, UK government agencies have a specific style sheet they are expected to follow, which includes date formats.  https://www.gov.uk/guidance/style-guide

Comment: @Archimedean_Point  in this guide, apparently, you aren't supposed to use numbered dates in government communication but must instead spell out the month -- so never *09/04/2018* but instead *April 9 2018*.  Again, I'm not sure if this is a blanket rule or just a general suggestion.

Comment: No one uses that ISO thing. Maybe in chemistry or some other scientific context. But not in more usual ones.

Comment: @Lambie No one?  I almost exclusively use ISO 8601 dates.  They're quite common in computing these days.

Comment: @snailboat Well, I don't know your ***line of business*** but I have never  in all my business life used YYYY-MM-DD, 2018-04-13, in letters, documents, memos, etc. Maybe in science, and that I do not know.

Comment: In some lines of business, letters and memos are less common than sorted tables. That's the problem with saying "No one".

Answer (score 1):

The formats both mean the same thing (either April 9 or September 4).  Stating numbers without leading zeroes is the standard when mentioning a date in isolation or as part of a sentence, e.g. "The tournament will start accepting entries on 4/9/2018."

Normally you would use leading zeroes in your date format when you have a column of dates and you want your column to look good and be more readable; having the date parts aligned vertically is much more visually pleasing than letting them jump around.  Consider:

> *the ugly way:*
>   4/9/2018
>   5/13/2018
>   11/17/2018
>   12/1/2018
>   12/24/2018
>
> *prettier, easier to read:*
>   04/09/2018
>   05/13/2018
>   11/17/2018
>   12/01/2018
>   12/24/2018

Comment: Yes, but everyone says/writes ***9/11***, not ***09/11*** (and I've already forgotten the year! :(

Comment: 9/11 is a special case, so is the British one, 7/7.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it was 2001.  (Also that falls under the "in isolation or as part of a sentence" situation, where you don't want leading zeroes.)

Comment: The zeroes can also help with sorting, although YYYY-MM-DD is best for that.

Comment: I just noticed today that my [driver's license](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1692&bih=955&q=driver%27s+license&oq=driver%27s+license) uses leading zeroes on all dates (date of birth, expiration date, etc.), even though these dates aren't in columns.